# Creating list throws error

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I am learning python and trying out to parse and create list from certain part of the logs.

```
09 Jan 2011 11:24:02 UTC,09 Jan 2011 11:24:02 UTC,5,,,,32871237,,,Finance [triEvent] imported to [Jan:9|AOL Deal|Restricted New||Low_Val_PASS|Low_Val_PASS|Low| transId=32871237 region=US in=347 out=2308 Significance=Error category=finance Outcome=/Failure art=1382919579 cat=main deviceResponse=200 act=OBSERVED URI=/All Trans/fiance System suser=u98932 dst=10.1.1.1 fileType=text/javascript;charset=utf-8 request=https://www.dsakdjasdj.org/graphs/concepts/expect_and_var#focus=problem&mode=learn
```

Heres my code to create new list which eventually i will use to create Dictionary.

```
path = 'D:/\TestFie'
new_list = ['transId', 'region', 'in', 'out']
new_dict = {}
val_list = []
with open( path, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')  
    for word in reader:
            d= word[9]
            start = d.find('transId')
            d= d[start:].split(' ')
            new = d[0].split("=")[1]
            val_list.append(new)
    print Counter(val_list)
```

If i print "new" i get values from trandId but the value is not appending to list and i keep getting error:

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 64, in <module>
    new = d[0].split("=")[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Basically i want to create dictionary for some certain part of log which have key value pair separated by "=" sign problem is that certain part of log such as URL and comment can have "=" sign as well.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The field you are trying to split on spaces has key values that contain spaces!  eg `URI=/All Trans/fiance`

Comment: so URI should take value "/All after splitting right ? any other alternate instead of splitting ?